# How do I configure Spring Security authentication to deal with a complex Active Directory / LDAP account tree?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, spring-security

(Context: I'm an experienced programmer, but new to LDAP, AD and Spring.)

We are a Windows shop, so all of our authentication is done with Active Directory. We are attempting to integrate a third-party product that is written in Java, so it does all of its authentication using Spring Security. So far, so good -- they've done that integration before, and there's a good deal online about how to set things up.

The problem is, our AD setup is a bit complex: in particular, our user accounts exist in various nodes in the AD/LDAP tree. To give a simplified example, say the LDAP tree looks like this:

```
DC=my-domain,DC=com
+ CN=Users
++ CN=user1,CN=Users,DC=my-domain,DC=com
+ CN=Staff
++ CN=user2,CN=Staff,DC=my-domain,DC=com
```

The thing is, all of the examples I have found let me authenticate *either* user1 or user2, but not both. That is, the following XML snippet will work to authenticate user1 against roles defined under "Groups":

```
<security:ldap-server url="ldap://my-domain.com:389" manager-dn="CN=manager_svc,OU=System Users,DC=my-domain,DC=com" manager-password="MyPa55w0rd"/>

<security:ldap-authentication-provider
          user-dn-pattern=""
          user-search-base="CN=Users,DC=my-domain,DC=com"
          user-search-filter="(&amp;(sAMAccountName={0})(objectclass=user))"
          group-search-base="OU=Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
          group-search-filter="member={0}"
          />
```

but that won't authenticate user2, since he doesn't match the user-search-base. Contrariwise, I can change user-search-base to `CN=Staff,DC=my-domain,DC=com`, which will work for user2, but then it won't work for user1.

So the question is, how do I make this search work for user accounts that are scattered across the AD/LDAP tree? I can imagine two possibilities, but I haven't figured out how to do either yet:

- On the one hand, if I can make user-search-base multi-valued, that solves my problem easily and correctly: I just put in all of the locations where user accounts might be found. So far, all of my attempts to do this have met with one error or another, but I'm still experimenting.
- OTOH, there is Subtree scoping of the search. I can see in the interactive LDAP tools that search can be either single-level or subtree. Far as I can tell, Spring out of the box is doing single-level. I can see that the underlying FilterBasedLdapUserSearch class has a setSearchSubtree() method, which looks like what I want, but I can't find a way to set that to true from the XML. (For now, let's assume that it isn't feasible to change the underlying Java program.)

The first option would be ideal, since it is probably much more efficient, but if that isn't possible and the second is, I suspect we can make it work.

I have a suspicion that the second approach is possible using thorny bean hackery, but I know next to nothing about beans, so I'd rather not wade into those thickets by myself. Does anybody have a good recipe to recommend?

Thanks much for any guidance you can provide...

Answer (score 3):

You could try searching from the domain root, if that is feasible, though that can cause problems with AD.

Alternatively, use of explicit [bean configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ldap-bean-config) is probably your best option. You can inject a custom `LdapUserSearch` implementation into the `BindAuthenticator` bean, which searches under all the necessary locations. If you look at the example in the docs, it shows a `FilterBasedLdapUserSearch` configuration. You could either use a couple of these, or implement the interface yourself from scratch. Here's a quick hack as an example:

```
public class CustomLdapSearch implements LdapUserSearch {
    public static final String SAM_FILTER="(&(sAMAccountName={0})(objectclass=user))"

    final LdapUserSearch users;
    final LdapUserSearch staff;

    public CustomLdapSearch(BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource) {
        users = new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch("CN=Users,DC=my-domain,DC=com", SAM_FILTER, contextSource);
        staff = new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch("CN=Staff,DC=my-domain,DC=com", SAM_FILTER, contextSource);

    }

    public DirContextOperations searchForUser(String username) {
        try {
            return users.searchForUser(username);
        } catch(UsernameNotFoundException e) {
            return staff.searchForUser(username);
        }
    }
}
```

Then change the `BindAuthenticator` configuration to:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
 <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
 <property name="userSearch" ref="customSearch"/>
</bean>

<bean id="customSearch" class="CustomLdapSearch">
 <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: This answer was helpful, but it's got issues. For example: You declared "users" and "staff" as LdapSearch when they should be LdapUserSearch. You also declared them final but didn't set them to anything.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code. The fields are set in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by using a searchBase with the empty string value (this uses the root as the searchbase, just like prule's answer), but I also had to set the property "referral" to "follow", otherwise I got a PartialResultException!

```
DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(...);
contextSource.setReferral("follow");
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar with spring-security-2.0.x using FilterBasedLdapUserSearch - where users were spread across multiple nodes:

```
<bean id="ldapUserSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <constructor-arg value=""/> <!-- optional sub-tree here -->
    <constructor-arg value="(&amp;(sAMAccountName={0})(objectclass=user))"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
</bean>


<bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
      class="org.springframework.security.providers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.providers.ldap.authenticator.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
            <property name="userSearch" ref="ldapUserSearch"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="userDetailsContextMapper"/>
</bean>


<bean id="contextSource"
      class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://localhost:10389/CN=Users,DC=my-domain,DC=com"/>
<!-- you may or may not need to connect with an account that can search -->
    <!--<property name="userDn" value="uid=admin,ou=system"/>-->
    <!--<property name="password" value="secret"/>-->
</bean>
```